# как изменить значение input="color"

Tags: javascript, jquery

как изменить цвет input="color" при вводе значения в `color-scheme__log-input-text`

```js
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keypress", function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.val().length < 7) {
    if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
      self.val("#" + self.val());
    }
    var color = self.val();
    $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.color-scheme {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color-scheme__container {
  display: flex;
}

.color-scheme__item {
  width: 100%;
}

.color-scheme__column:first-of-type {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color-scheme__column:last-of-type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-scheme__input-color {
  display: block;
  height: auto !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 140px;
}

.color-scheme__color-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.color-scheme__input-color-pick {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -7px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-scheme__container">
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <input type="text" class="color-scheme__input-color color-scheme__log-input-text" name="login_but_text">
  </div>
  <div class="color-scheme__column">
    <div class="color-scheme__color-container">
      <input id="input-color-6" class="color-scheme__input-color-pick color-scheme__log-btn-text" value="#000" type="color">
    </div>
    <label class="color-scheme__input-color-label" for="input-color-6">click to pick color</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("keypress", function() {
            var self = $(this);
            if (self.val().length < 7) {
                if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
                    self.val("#" + self.val());
                }
                var color = self.val();
                $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on("change", function() {
            var color = $(this).val();
            $(".color-scheme__log-btn-tex").value = color;
            $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так (цвет будет меняться когда в поле 7 символов):

```
$(".color-scheme__log-input-text").on('input', function() {
    var self = $(this);

    if (self.val().length < 7) {
        if (self.val()[0] != "#") {
            self.val("#" + self.val());
        }
        var color = self.val();

        $(".color-scheme__log-btn-text").val(color);
    } else if(self.val().length = 7) {

        $('#input-color-6').val(self.val());
    }

    else {
        return false;

    }
});
```

Comment: цвет нужно поменять когда я введу в Input='text' номер цвета #060606